# Remove azurewebsites from the site's domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have one site call https://[site-name].azurewebsites.net. I just want to remove .azurewebsites from the entire link so It suppose to look a like            https://[site-name].net. Is there any way to make changes in the Azure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to map a custom domain to your Web App. See [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name) for details.

And then [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate) explains how to bring in the cert for your domain name.

Comment: Note that you obviously need SSL certificate for your domain too.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if you want https, then yes, of course. I updated the answer.